# Continuous Increase in Memory Usage Issue in Langchain Utilization

Tags: python, flask, chatbot, openai-api, langchain

In my Flask application, I store my data using Langchain and Faiss. However, with each operation, memory usage increases and never decreases. I tested this with multiple vector databases, but memory usage consistently goes up. How can I solve this problem?

**My code:**

```
def upload_data():
    text = request.get_json().get('text')

    text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=150)
    docs = text_splitter.split_text(text)

    FAISS.from_texts(docs, OpenAIEmbeddings()).save_local("faiss_index")

    return "Success"
```

I tried changing multiple vector databases.

Comment: If you use `gunicorn`, you can use a trick to solve by using config `--max-requests`

Comment: Make sure you are not using any pirate software, this may be one of the reason for memory usage spike.

Comment: @ZKS I debugged using memory-profiler, and it seems that the issue is likely stemming from the tiktoken encoding process in the OpenAIEmbeddings class.

this code:

`encoding = tiktoken.encoding_for_model(model_name)`

Comment: @TanThien I will use this configuration in production until the mentioned problem is resolved  thx :)